# Turning off Rails in Mac Terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I'm learning to use Bootstrap and spent the last few hours wrestling with Terminal as I tried to install the software that accompanies it - Ruby, Rails, SASS and two or three more. It was a failure, though I did get most of the programs installed.

Now it appears that Rails has hijacked my Terminal. I tried installing another toy I wanted to try out, Symfony. When I type in the install command

```
$ curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer > symfony.phar
$ sudo mv symfony.phar /usr/local/bin/symfony
$ chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

I get this message:

```
-bash: $: command not found
Davids-MacBook-Pro:Rail myname$
```

I get the same message if I type in $ php --version

Anyway, the word "Rail" leads me to suspect that Terminal is in Rails mode. Can anyone tell me how to turn it off? I wasn't allowed to ask about it on the Apple forum; they seem to have a problem with questions related to this topic. ;)

Thanks.

P.S. I'm using OSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands to install symfony, make sure you enter them one at a time and don't include the `$` which is causing the error.

You can configure what appears currently as

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:Rail myname$
```

by going typing `cd` to go to your home directory and than `nano .bash_profile`

By the way Bootstrap is just a css, html, and a bit of javascript framework/library that you can use with a bunch of different languages doesn't have to be Ruby on Rails. Also ruby is installed on yosemite by default but you might need to update it and Rails automatically includes SASS (Both Rails and SASS are gems).

Answer (score 0):

The `:Rail` in `Davids-MacBook-Pro:Rail myname$` indicates that you're currently in a folder named `Rail`. There is no "Rails mode," and Rails will not "hijack" your terminal.

Type the `pwd` command to reveal which folder you're in (which I'm guessing is a folder named `Rail`).

If you `cd` into another folder, your command prompt will update to reflect that:

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:Rail myname$ cd ~/Desktop
Davids-MacBook-Pro:Desktop myname$
```